# Animaciones CSS3 o JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, css, css3

¿Qué diferencia hay entre las animaciones que puedes crear con CSS3 y con Javascript?
¿En que ocasiones es mejor utilizar unas u otras?

Answer (score 2):

a mi punto de vista es

CSS. Hojas de Estilo en Cascada (Cascading Style Sheets) es el lenguaje utilizado para describir la presentación de documentos HTML o XML

es decir que CSS es mas adecuado para dar estilo a las paginas y no provee demasiada iteraccion con el usuario ya que no es parte de su funcionalidad.

ahora Js 
su funcionalidad se centra mas en la interaccion con el usuario, eventos(click, dbclick, keyworks, etc)

si bien es cierto que tambien se puede hacer animaciones con css, no son potentes animaciones, ya que en realidad son simples transiciones animadas